# I want to make a increasing number using winform MVP pattern in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label, mvp, flowlayoutpanel

Hi I'm practicing using winform MVP pattern in C#.

I made Models, Presenters and Views folders, and they has a each class.
(Models has Data.cs, Presenters has Datapresenter.cs and View have interface.cs and Form.cs)

I used 'FlowLayoutPanel'. and I made Label to make numbers. Like this.

My progress so far.

[image: Form what I made]

Here is Data.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutSample.Models
{
    public class Data
    {

        public string label { get; set; }

        public string CalculateArea()
        {
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is DataPresenter.cs (Presenter)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using LayoutSample.Models;
using LayoutSample.Views;

namespace LayoutSample.Presenters
{
    public class DataPresenter
    {
        IFlowLabel LabelView;

        public DataPresenter(IFlowLabel view)
        {
            LabelView = view;
        }

        public void CalculateArea()
        {
            Data data = new Models.Data();
            data.label = string.Copy(LabelView.label);
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    Panel flowLayoutPanel1 = new Panel();
                    label.Text = i.ToString();
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            });
            th.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is interface.cs(View)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutSample.Views
{
    public interface IFlowLabel
    {
        string label { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and this is Form.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using LayoutSample.Models;
using LayoutSample.Presenters;
using LayoutSample.Views;

namespace LayoutSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IFlowLabel
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        string IFlowLabel.label
        {
            get
            {
                return flowLayoutPanel1.ToString();
            }

            set
            {
                if (flowLayoutPanel1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        flowLayoutPanel1.Text = value;
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Text = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.AutoSize = false;
                label.Width = 50;
                label.Text = i.ToString();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            DataPresenter presenter = new DataPresenter(this);
            presenter.CalculateArea();
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I want to make the numbers increasing.

How could I increase them at same time?

p.s
I've changed DataPresenter.cs

I've chagned public void Calculate Area() to

```
public void CalculateArea()
    {
        Data data = new Models.Data();
        data.label = string.Copy(LabelView.label);
        var th = new Thread(() =>
       {
           for ( int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
           {
               for (int j=1; j<101;j++)
               {
                   Label label = new Label();
                   label.Text = j.ToString();              
                   Console.WriteLine(label);
               }
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
           }
       });
       th.Start();
    }
```

I can watch the numbers increasing via console, but I can't see the change in WimForm. How can I bring the increment to WinForm??

Comment: Do you mean every single number should be incremented at the same time`? Or what exactly do you mean by "increase them"?

Comment: @Luchespeter  Sorry about confusing. I want to make every single number increment at same time.

Comment: ok in that case you can do two things: 
1. Refill the FlowLayoutPanel with all new labels with increased numbers or
2. Save References to all labels into an array or list and then loop through them an increment their values.
The incrementing itself is rather easy. Just start your for-loop at 1 and go to i<101. You can do that with an int variable to keep it variable. (I guess option 2 would be nicer)

Comment: @Luchspeter i edited my question. if you don't mind can you check it?